# Writing a query for multiple fields using IN

Tags: sql

```
SELECT a.First_Name,b.EMPID,c.Phn
FROM NAME a,Emp b,Phone c
WHERE b.Emptype = 'New'
AND a.First_name,b.Last_name,C.Phn = (SELECT a.First_Name,b.Last_name,c.Phn
FROM NAME a,Emp b,Phone c
WHERE b.Emptype = 'Old')
```

Basically, I want to search for new customers which have the same details (First name, Last name and Phone) as the old customers. An old customer can be converted into a new customer but its details are retained. Hence, the only thing that changes is the emptype.

Eg. (John McEnroe 47589876 Old) when converted becomes (John McEnroe 475898876 New)
[First_name,Last_name,Phone,Emptype]

Comment: Fix your query to use proper `join` syntax.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: You are creating cross joins between your tables because you are not joining them at all. I'm 100% certain that you do **not** want that.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, here's a query that uses EXISTS.
The main difference between Exists and IN is that Exists queries using INDEX but IN goes like a lot of OR toghether.

```
SELECT a.First_Name
    ,b.EMPID
    ,c.Phn
FROM NAME a
    ,Emp b
    ,Phone c
WHERE b.Emptype = 'New'
    AND EXISTS (Select TOP 1 1 FROM
                    NAME x
                    ,Emp y
                    ,Phone z
                WHERE
                    x.First_Name = a.First_Name
                AND y.Last_name = b.Last_name
                AND z.Phn = c.Phn
                AND y.Emptype = 'Old'
            )
```

Now, looking at your query, you have 3 tables, not joined toghether (Name, Emp, Phone) so you have a real mess with the data that will come as an output. Will be, basically this formula:

(1st Table rows qty) Multiplied by (2nd Table rows qty) Multiplied by (3rd Table rows qty)

Means that if each table have 100 rows, you'll get this:

100 x 100 x 100 = 1000000 Rows in the result (Awful right?)

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH tempTable as (
       SELECT a.First_Name,b.EMPID,c.Phn
          FROM NAME a,Emp b,Phone c
          where b.Emptype = 'Old'
      )
select a.First_Name,b.EMPID,c.Phn
          FROM NAME a,Emp b,Phone c,tempTable t
          where b.Emptype = 'Old' and a.First_Name = t.First_Name
                AND b.Last_name = t.Last_name
                AND c.Phn = t.Phn;
```

try this... or use subquery...

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use multiple columns for an `IN` query:

```
AND (a.First_name,b.Last_name,C.Phn) IN (SELECT a.First_Name,b.Last_name,c.Phn
                                         FROM ... )
```